# Quartz not working in Grails4, Issue in dependency not able to compile

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-4

Getting error in Scheduler Dependency i'm using grails4 :
Anyone let me know correct dependency for scheduler

```
dependencies {
compile "org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.1"
```

}

and also tried this:

```
dependencies {
compile "com.agileorbit:schwartz:1.0.1"
```

}

Both are not able to compile:

> grails run-app
>   | Resolving Dependencies. Please wait...

| Running application...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':compileGroovy'.

  > org/quartz/JobExecutionContext
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to add the quartz dependency explicitly in addition to the plugin as Gradle 5 stopped pulling in transitive dependancies. Also I'd suggest using the latest version (2.0.13 vs 2.0.1 which is quite old)

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13' // Needed to compile *Job classes
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'
    compile 'org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.1' // Is not pulled in by default
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We're using quartz in grails4 applications with:

```
dependencies {
    //...
    compile("org.quartz-scheduler:quartz:2.2.3") {
        exclude group: 'slf4j-api', module: 'c3p0'
    }
    compile ('org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13') 
}
```

here's the issue description on github: https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-quartz/issues/107